# How to allow text with spaces in SQL from c# Textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code that lets you input sentences in a textbox and it inserts in a table in SQL Server

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl_notes (Notes,date_time) Values('" + txtbox_Notes.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", con);
   com.ExecuteNonQuery();
   txtbox_Notes.Text = "";
}
```

but when I press the button that calls this function, it gives out the Error

> String or binary data would be truncated

Comment: You should probably use parameterized queries.

Comment: Your SQL column is not set to accept the length of the `note` you are trying to insert.  Either change the column length, or truncate the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the length of the string you are trying to insert in the `Notes` column, is longer than the maximum allowed size in that column's definition. Try truncating the value for `txtbox_Notes.Text` to the specified column length.

I would also suggest you read a little bit about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and take into account that the way you are executing this insertion command is **really** vulnerable to this kind of attacks. As suggested in a comment for the question, you could also use stored procedures to execute the insertion which not only provides a (thin) layer of security but also makes your code more readable.

Comment: If I used stored procedure, will it be safe from SQL Injection?

Comment: Definitely safer than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameters in your query, otherwise you are making it very error prone and also an easy hack for SQL injection.

Just try something like this and see if it work for you

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl_notes (Notes,date_time) Values(@Notes,@DateTime)", con);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Notes", txtbox_Notes.Text));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTime", DateTime.Now));
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        txtbox_Notes.Text = "";
    }
```